# wait until the end of Chefs compile phase before running code block?

Tags: chef-infra

I want to check the contents of the `resource_collection` within a recipe to see if a specific LWRP is being called during the nodes run. But due to the compile load logic and cookbook name ordering etc.. it's difficult to do something like this:

```
if run_context.resource_collection.any?{|r| r.resource_name.to_s == 'my_lwrp_resource'}

    template "/tmp/example.rb" do
      source      "test.erb"
      action      :nothing
    end.run_action(:create)

end
```

because this code might be run before all resources have been added to the resource_collection.

Is there any way to defer running this code until the end of the compile phase to ensure the `resource_collection` is fully populated and the query will correctly find the resource ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can define a [ruby_block](https://docs.chef.io/resource_ruby_block.html) resource that will be executed during converge. You won't have access to the recipe DSL there, to define the template resource using the DSL, but defining a template resource in ruby is just as easy:

```
ruby_block 'run_my_template_resource' do
  action :create
  block do
    r = Chef::Resource::Template.new('template_name', run_context)
    r.path       '/path/to/write.to'
    r.source     'source.erb'
    r.cookbook   'cookbook-name'
    r.owner      'root'
    r.group      'root'
    r.mode       00600
    r.variables  my: 'variables'
    r.run_action :create
  end
end
```